# $A$, a linearly independent subset of a subspace $S$; $x\notin S$; show $A\cup\{x\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be a linearly independent subset of a subspace $S$.
>   If $x\notin S$, show that $A\cup\{x\}$ is linearly independent.

**Theorem**:
*Let $B$ be linearly independent and $y\notin B$. Then, $B\cup\{y\}$ is linearly dependent iff $y\in Span(B)$.*
Using this theorem, I get that-
$A$ is linearly independent and $x\notin S\Rightarrow x\notin A$.
So, $A\cup\{x\}$is linearly independent iff $x\notin Sp(A)$.
Therefore, it should be enough to show that-
$A\subseteq S$ (where, $A$ is linearly independent) and $x\notin S$
$\Rightarrow x\notin Sp(A)$ $_{...(1)}$
$\Rightarrow A\cup\{x\}$ is linearly independent $_{...(2)}$

---

My question is, if my approach is correct how should I prove $(1)$ because $(2)$ obviously follows from there. Or is my approach incorrect?
[There are similar questions on the site, but I couldn't find one for my approach.]

Comment: According to your approach, take $A = S = \left\lbrace \left( 1, 0 \right) \right\rbrace$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, take $x = \left( 2, 0 \right) \notin S$. Is the set $S \cup \left\lbrace x \right\rbrace$ linearly independent? Talking of ($1$) you mentioned, is $\left( 2, 0 \right) \notin \text{Span } \left( S \right)$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh word. Then, can you please explain where I am going wrong and what I should do.

Comment: Well, according to the statement you need to prove, it is already given to you that $x \notin \text{Span } \left( S \right)$. So, you need to start with it. If it is not in the span, what can you say about the dependence equation?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh wait, so~ since $x\notin S$ and $A$ is a linearly independent subset of S, then $x\notin Span(A)$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Then, my approach is incorrect because the corollary is wrong? What should be the correct method?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh $S$ is a subspace. So, in your example, $S=\{(1,0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is wrong

Comment: Yes. My bad! Well then, you just need to prove that $\text{Span } \left( S \right) = S$ given that $S$ is a subspace. Then things will get easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you overdid it a little bit.  With the theorem we are pretty much done, since $x\not\in S\implies x\not\in\operatorname{span}A$.

Comment: As @AniruddhaDeshmukh pointed out with an example, the corollary I mentioned is wrong somewhere. Hence, please explain how $x\notin span(A)\Rightarrow A\cup\{x\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Suppose we have a linear combination of the elements of $A$ and $x$ equal to zero.   Then it has to be the trivial one.